# Django create session which does not destroy after logout

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-sessions

In my django project I want a session which only destroys after a certain time, for that I set the expire time but session is also destroying after logout.

Basically what I want to a session which is **not effected by any login/logout activity.**

I search it for but not found any solution, anyone help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, when you call `logout`, it [flushes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/sessions/#django.contrib.sessions.backends.base.SessionBase.flush) the session. If you want to keep that data, then you need to define your own logout functionality. You can try like that:

```
from django.contrib.auth import logout

def logout(request):
    your_data = request.session.get('your_key', None)
    current_expiry = request.session.get('_session_expiry')
    logout(request)
    if your_data:
        request.session['your_key'] = your_data
        if current_expiry:
           request.session['_session_expiry'] = current_expiry
```

**FYI** Its an untested code. Also, Maybe its better if you don't use session for storing data which should last after logout. You can use redis or any temporary storage for this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, how can I use redis without using it in default django caches ?

Comment: Well, you don't need to define it as default django  cache. You can look into this package: https://pypi.org/project/redis/. Hope it helps.

Comment: it is working fine but I don't know how.

Answer (score -1):

**Try This:**

**`Views.py`**

```
from django.contrib.auth import logout

def logoutUser(request):
    logout(request)
    messages.success(request,"Successfully logged out")
    return redirect("login")
```